# Symbolic links in Windows

Tags: windows, linux, symlink

I am using a huge data-base of images. This database gets duplicated every time I create a new test using the image data-base. So in Linux, I use Link file to a common database set.

Now, I am in Windows,
Is there any way we can use the Linux link to files or some equivalent in Windows. Or using some relative file path is the only way out?

Comment: can you help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403772/how-to-use-reuse-softlinks-created-on-mac-in-windows-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like [Reparse points](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365503(VS.85).aspx)? These are somewhat like a symbolic link on linux. If you need a way to view your linux partition, something like [Ext2Ifs](http://www.fs-driver.org/) may be of interest to you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403772/how-to-use-reuse-softlinks-created-on-mac-in-windows-8 can youplease have alook at it here

Answer (score 2):

You mean [Junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use file Symbolic links. See [here for more info](http://www.shell-shocked.org/article.php?id=284) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) too