# How to use reuse softlinks created on Mac in Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, windows-phone-8, symlink

I have few softlinks, says 1000 images which i have created in MacBook Pro which i am using in my iOS Apps.

Now i am porting the same app in Windows 8 phone app, so i want to reuse the same Softlink in Windows phone 8 apps as well, so how can i use that ?

I have tried to open the softlink in Windows 8 machine, but it says that the "File format is not supported".

I have both the original file and the softlink in my Windows machine.

Is there anyother way that i can reuse the same soft link ? if NOT what is the best approach that i can follow.

**EDIT**

Ok, here is some more info on this :

**In MacBook Pro**

I have a folder in desktop which has physical paths (actual images), now i have created softlinks using a script and these softlinks are placed in some different folder.

Now i am using these soflinks in my iOS app.

**In Windows 8**

I have copied the folder which has soflink as well as the folder which has actual files in it from Mac.

Now i have pasted actual files folder on my desktop and soflinks folder in some D: drive now if i go my soflink folder in D drive and when i check those images it shows blank, because its not pointing to the actual files.

I have both actual files folder and also the soflink folder.

One more point is that when you create a soflink, in MacBook Pro it shows this icon :[image]

But on Windows 8 its blank nothing like that.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the symbolic links? You can't copy a symbolic link from  OS X  to Windows (and have it work).

Comment: @WiredPrairie thanks, i am trying to display the soflinks which are images, but i cant use that so is there any other approach ? like i can REUSE those images which are softlinks as is ?

Comment: Where are the images that they had pointed to?

Comment: I have both the Original folder and the Folder which has symlinks of those images in my C Drive

Comment: You can use the original images. Not anything else.

Comment: No i cant use the original images, thats the problem i have many many files like that, and tomorrow if the file is modified then again i cant copy that file and use that, this is advantage of syslinks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46225/discussion-between-wiredprairie-and-goofy)

Comment: hey, are they all in one path

Comment: @SeeSharp yes, ihave my original file in one folder and its softlinks in another folder, but i am not able to recognise that its a softlink, but the images are not opening

Comment: @Goofy it looks like you +1 my answer but didn't mark it as the correct answer with the checkmark.  If the answer is correct, please give it a check as well so that I can receive the +50 bounty that you offered.  It expires in 3 days.  Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelYasumoto - Just +1-ed you so you actually qualify for the half-bounty if the OP doesn't award it.

Comment: hey @Goofy did you solve the problem

Comment: @SeeSharp No not yet, can you help me on this ?

Comment: You question is very good, but to be honest with you i have no idea, there is almost non information about this topic. My suspicions are that there is no way to use symbolic links in windows phone

Comment: @SeeSharp yes, i have even searched a lot, but if i cant use in this way then what is the best approach that i follow, thats what i am looking for

Comment: @SeeSharp have you worked on Windows 8 phone app development ?

Comment: i have a few applicants in windows store :)

Comment: @SeeSharp i have few doubts can you please help me ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21629249/how-to-use-resourcedictionary-in-phone-class-library-project

Answer (score 5):

Your question is missing a couple of details so I'm going to have to make a guess about your situation.  The problem is:

> You created some symlinks using OS X on a file system and now you are
>   having problems accessing those symlinks in Windows.

Unless you did something tricky, like installing 3rd party file system drivers, then the only file system that both Windows and OS X can read/write to natively is FAT based.  So I'm guessing your situation is:

> You created some symlinks using OS X on a FAT32 file system and now
>   you are having problems accessing those symlinks in Windows.

Assuming the above situation, the problem is that there are no symlinks in FAT32 because the file system doesn't support them.  OS X is tricking you because it "just works".  What is really happening is that OS X is creating an ASCII text file that contains the line "XSym" along with the name of the file it is "linking" to, plus some file system information.  You can confirm this by opening your softlinks on your Windows system in notepad.  Normally you would see binary code if you were opening an actual image in notepad, but instead you should see the text from these fake symlinks.

So, what do you do?  I see a couple of options:

1. You could use a file system that supports soft links.  This could mean using HFS+ (OS X file system) which would require you to install HFS+ drivers on your Windows system so that it can read/write to the file system.  Or it could mean going in the other direction and using NTFS (Windows file system) which would require you to install NTFS drivers on your Mac.  Note that most recent versions of OS X can read NTFS file systems, they just can't write to them.
2. You could use the fake symlinks that OS X is creating.  This would require writing a parser to interpret the links or finding a library that does this for you.  I don't have a copy, but I believe the XSym format is covered in the "OS X Internals" book.
3. You could rethink the approach to your problem so that it doesn't require you to use symlinks.

If this didn't solve your problem, then please provide more details because I had to make some guesses about your situation.

==EDIT==

Take a look at the subversion documentation on symbolic links [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.tour.cycle.html).
The relevant quote from the doc is:

> Versioning Symbolic Links
>
> On non-Windows platforms, Subversion is able to version files of the
>   special type symbolic link (or “symlink”). A symlink is a file that
>   acts as a sort of transparent reference to some other object in the
>   filesystem, allowing programs to read and write to those objects
>   indirectly by way of performing operations on the symlink itself.
>
> When a symlink is committed into a Subversion repository, Subversion
>   remembers that the file was in fact a symlink, as well as the object
>   to which the symlink “points.” When that symlink is checked out to
>   another working copy on a non-Windows system, Subversion reconstructs
>   a real filesystem-level symbolic link from the versioned symlink. But
>   that doesn't in any way limit the usability of working copies on
>   systems such as Windows that do not support symlinks. On such systems,
>   Subversion simply creates a regular text file whose contents are the
>   path to which to the original symlink pointed. While that file can't
>   be used as a symlink on a Windows system, it also won't prevent
>   Windows users from performing their other Subversion-related
>   activities.

Basically, it says something similar to what I mentioned earlier, which is that symlinks are not supported that well if at all on Windows systems.  Subversion just creates text files with the contents of the link so you can choose to either figure out how to parse these text files yourself or try to find a library that will parse them for you.

Comment: please see my edit, hope i have given enough information on this topic, if you require anything please let me know.

Comment: @Goofy You didn't mention where this folder is being created.  Are you creating the folder in OS X on an external USB drive, or a network share, or a separate partition on the computer?  Also, are you using Bootcamp to run Windows on the same computer to access these files or are they on a removable file system that you are able to attach to Windows?  Either way, it sounds like your problem is what I described which means your solution is one of the 3 points I mentioned above.

Comment: ok, to be specific again i have these folder in my SVN and i have checked out those two folders(folder with actual files and folder containing softlinks) on Macbook as well as Windows 8.I hope its clear now

Comment: You never mentioned that you are using the SVN RCS to transfer the files between systems.  See edit above.

Comment: I have checked these folders on Ubuntu and as well as on Mac , and it works fine, i mean i am able to see those images, now my question is i have not used SVN but still i have copied the files in a USB drive and  pasted onto my Windows machine, but stil its not working, i need to some how find a way to reuse those links on Winodws machine and i need you help on that

Comment: @Goofy, correct. The USB drive is FAT32 which I mentioned in my main answer and does not support symlinks.  Your only options are the 3 solutions or choices that I mentioned earlier.  I suggest that you read each one carefully, pick one for your solution and implement it.

Comment: If I’m not mistaken, your claim that only FAT file systems are supported for both reading and writing on both OS X and Windows is false. [UDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Disk_Format) should be supported too, but you rarely hear about it.

Comment: Sure, as is CDFS/ISO9660 and other file systems used on optical media, but it doesn't sound like that is going to help in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is that there are so many links in one directory

> There is a maximum of 31 reparse points (and therefore symbolic links)
>   allowed in a particular path.

**See also**

- [Programming Considerations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365460%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: As far as i know symbolic links(soft links) are reparse points.

Comment: Your source doesn't talk about a maximum reparse points in a directory, but in a particular _path_, that is to say: a path with 32+ symlink compounds (eg. `/link1/link2/link3/.../link32/link33`) would fail.

Comment: For starters the information what side created the symlink is missing. That's relevant, because while Windows has symlinks starting with Vista, [their semantics differ significantly](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/63174) compared to unixoid systems. So say the link was created on OSX and therefore its bits state that fact, a file system driver for Windows *might* arguably translate that transparently into a reparse point and handle it, but it would only make sense for a subset of relative symlinks. A symlink to an absolute path would make no sense whatsoever without extra "hints".

Comment: It would still require special handling in that file system driver and for the majority of linked paths a meaningful "translation" might still be impossible.

Answer (score 1):

I know I am late in this, but I hope that others may benefit from my answer, even though the asker may long have moved on.

### Some background

Symbolic link semantics differ considerably between unixoid systems and Windows. As was stated before, Windows uses reparse points to implement symbolic links and junction points (some deduplication features on the Server editions also seem to use it).

Now, a reparse point contains extra data as a hint to the I/O manager and object manager. Essentially, based on a reparse point tag (a GUID) the type of reparse point can be determined and then a file system filter driver handles the details. You can find a moderately detailed description of this in the 6th edition of "Windows Internals" in chapter 9 or in a recent Windows Driver Kit or on MSDN under [`REPARSE_GUID_DATA_BUFFER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365500.aspx) (and related topics).

On unixoid systems the file system metadata also contains a clue that the (text file) is a symlink. If you use `ls -l` that clue is visible in the form of a leading `l`, e.g. in:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 user group         38 2015-10-12 11:51
```

The actual contents of symlinks are system-specific as well, on Linux for example they contain merely the target path.

What the Windows and *nix symlinks share is that the target needn't exist at the time of creation. Also on Windows a symlink can point to a network location, which is special *because* on Windows network paths differ from local paths.

### Possible compatibility

Assuming a symlink was created on the OSX or Linux side, we can imagine certain levels of compatibility. If the file system driver on the Windows side would now present symlinks as reparse points and some party (either said file system driver or a file system filter) would handle these reparse points, it would be possible to interpret the target path of a symlink in some way.

Converting forward slashes to backward slashes is the least concern, however.

In [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/63174) I already outlined a few cases where there would be no meaningful translation possible.

Essentially the only type of symlinks for which I would see a potential for compatibility are **relative symlinks**. But even for those is is necessary to point out that the target path may not point outside of the folder hierarchy that is visible on the Windows side. That is, if your symlink on the OSX or Linux side resides *inside* `/var/www/html` and points to `../../../something` it becomes meaningless in a case where `/var` is the mounted volume on Windows.

If, however, such symlink `/var/www/html/foobar` and pointed to `../html1/foo/bar` chances are that if `/var` was the mounted volume on OSX or Linux and now on Windows, the relative target path still makes sense (after adjustments such as forward to backward slashes etc).

For any absolute target paths, the file system driver or the file system filter driver would have to get some hints on how to translate the source form of a symlink into the target form.

E.g. if a symlink pointed to `/home/foo/bar` the `/home` part might translate to a specific mounted volume.

But you can already see that this requires a lot of user intervention, which is probably why most people would consider it futile to even attempt a meaningful translation.

### Possible workaround for SVN

A possible workaround for you could be to use SVN externals. It depends on the exact scenario, but since you are using SVN they come to mind.

You can think of SVN externals as Subversion's native symlinks. I have used them this way and I know of several others who have, but I don't know how widespread that train of thought and subsequent usage is.

Attention: externals pointing to *files* were only introduced in SVN 1.6, so this may or may not be an issue in your scenario.

[SVN externals come in several flavors](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.externals.html). You can set them for folders or files (files only with 1.6 and newer).

And an external can point to:

1. an external repo (`schema://server/path`)
2. relative to the same repo (`^/path`)
3. relative to the schema (`//server/path`) or
4. relative to the parent directory

You'll probably want 2 or 4 from that list. Most likely you'll want 4, though, because *file externals* must point to the same repository.

#### Long story short

If your images are in a folder such as `trunk/images` and you have a folder `trunk/platforms/windows/images` you can either set the the `svn:externals` property on `trunk/platforms/windows` to have an external named `images` pointing to `../../images` (i.e. directory external) or, assuming you wanted to use a different hierarchy or different names underneath `trunk/platforms/windows/images` you could create *file externals* like so (`images` subdirectory must exist in WC):

```
cd trunk/platforms/windows
svn propedit svn:externals images
```

and add individual externals like this:

```
../../../images/filename.jpeg other-filename.jpeg
```

Please note that the target directories need to exist in the repository and the working copy, so for an external like this:

```
../../../images/filename.jpeg foo/other-filename.jpeg
```

the subdirectory `trunk/platforms/windows/images/foo` *must* exist.

Updating your working copy will result in those externals to manifest as versioned files inside the working copy. So they are a type of symlinks that exists in SVN and manifests as proper files in the working copy, which means *all* platforms can handle them equally.