# How to use ResourceDictionary in Windows Phone class library project

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, resourcedictionary

I have ResourceDictionary.xaml file in my Resources folder which has some style in it, i need to use this in my .cs file and xaml file as well how to use it?

Here is my ResourceDictionary.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls" 
    xmlns:controlsPrimitives="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Primitives;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls"
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit" 
    xmlns:toolkitPrimitives="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Primitives;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"  
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WP_Test">

    <!-- Resource dictionary entries should be defined here. -->
    <Style x:Key="LayoutRootStyle" TargetType="Grid">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    </Style>

    <!-- ***************************************** -->
    <Style x:Key="MainScreenButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,3,10,5"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.4"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                            <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

We generally do it in this way programatically in .cs file

```
button.Style = (Style)App.Current.Resources["MainScreenButtonStyle"];
```

But how can we access in Phone class library project ?

Answer (score 3):

actually it's quite simple just include `ResourceDictionary.xaml` file in your class library project, and you have samething like:

```
 public Button CreateButton() 
        {
            Button b = new Button();
            Application.Current.Resources.Source = new Uri("/ResourceDictionary.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
            b.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["MainScreenButtonStyle"];
            return b;
        }
```

Comment: i tried your solution, its giving me error, i have my ResourceDictionary.xaml in Resources folder of library project

Comment: First thing how to create a ResourceDictionary.xaml because in Phone class library project there is no such xml by default

Comment: well i have added new xml file, then copy paste your code, and it's working for me

Comment: You  mean to say that , you have created a new Phone class library project and added a new .XAML file in that you have copy pasted the above code ? is it like this ?

Comment: can you please help me out i am stuck from long time

Comment: still no help see here as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671030/how-to-add-resourcedictionary-in-phone-class-library-project-and-access-it

Comment: hey bro [this is what i have done](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=3203ABC86044DD54%21161)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47148/discussion-between-goofy-and-see-sharp)

Comment: can you please have a look at this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21746433/how-to-add-list-item-selector-to-listbox

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your resources xaml to App.xaml to automatically detect it:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="myDict">
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```