# How to add ResourceDictionary in Phone class library project and access it

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, resourcedictionary

I am working on a project where i have child project which is referencing the library project.

In my Library project(Phone class library) how do i create ResourceDictionary.xaml where i need to add some styles and use it in xaml files and as well as .cs files.

I need to access styles in ResourceDictionary.xaml in my xaml files as well as .cs files how to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder as `Generic` in the root folder and have your resource files there...

**To access it in XAML**

```
  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Generic.xaml" />
  </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

or

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/AssembleName;component/Generic.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

**To access it in .cs**

```
new URI(pack://application:,,,/AssembleName;component/Generic.xaml)
```

Comment: First thing how to create a ResourceDictionary.xaml because in Phone class library project there is no such xml by default

Comment: Are you there ? can you please help me out ?

Comment: There is no direct way to create a Resource file to the project.. What i do is create an UserControl and deleting the cs file.. So it would be my resource file...

Comment: Can you show me how ? because i have created User Control .XAML file when i try to add resource, it gives me erro

Answer (score 0):

OK, Finally i solved it myself. here is how i solved it.

When you create `Phone Class Library Project` you will not the `ResourceDictionary.xaml by default`, so what create a xaml page,like how you create a normal xaml file.

```
Right click on solution ->Add New Item ->Windows Phone Portrait Page.
```

Now remove the .cs file that is created, add in the .XAML file add your style which is within `ResourceDictionary` tag.

The above is all done in `Library project.`

Now in the `child app:`

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="LibraryResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

suppose you have a style defined in ResourceDictionary as MainScreenButtonStyle you can set in this way

```
button.Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["MainScreenButtonStyle"] as Style;
```